# Smack autoreconnect is not retrying NoResponseException

Tags: android, smack

According to my understanding of autoreconnect module smack will retry to connect in case of any error or expection. I called connection.login() method and got the NoResponseException at this point i was expecting autoreconnect to retry to connect but it's not happening.

This is the exception i got

```
01-03 00:11:24.233 11157-11236/com.safarifone.waafi.debug W/System.err: org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException$NoResponseException: No response received within reply timeout. Timeout was 5000ms (~5s). Waited for response using: StanzaIdFilter: id=qZBnz-7.
01-03 00:11:24.238 11157-11236/com.safarifone.waafi.debug W/System.err:     at org.jivesoftware.smack.StanzaCollector.nextResultOrThrow(StanzaCollector.java:253)
01-03 00:11:24.238 11157-11236/com.safarifone.waafi.debug W/System.err:     at org.jivesoftware.smack.StanzaCollector.nextResultOrThrow(StanzaCollector.java:208)
01-03 00:11:24.239 11157-11236/com.safarifone.waafi.debug W/System.err:     at org.jivesoftware.smack.AbstractXMPPConnection.bindResourceAndEstablishSession(AbstractXMPPConnection.java:560)
01-03 00:11:24.239 11157-11236/com.safarifone.waafi.debug W/System.err:     at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection.loginInternal(XMPPTCPConnection.java:422)
01-03 00:11:24.239 11157-11236/com.safarifone.waafi.debug W/System.err:     at org.jivesoftware.smack.AbstractXMPPConnection.login(AbstractXMPPConnection.java:494)
01-03 00:11:24.240 11157-11236/com.safarifone.waafi.debug W/System.err:     at org.jivesoftware.smack.AbstractXMPPConnection.login(AbstractXMPPConnection.java:451)
01-03 00:11:24.241 11157-11236/com.safarifone.waafi.debug W/System.err:     at com.safarifone.im.core.xmpp.XmppConnection.connect(XmppConnection.java:141)
01-03 00:11:24.241 11157-11236/com.safarifone.waafi.debug W/System.err:     at com.safarifone.im.services.im.IMService.handleConnect(IMService.java:331)
01-03 00:11:24.242 11157-11236/com.safarifone.waafi.debug W/System.err:     at com.safarifone.im.services.im.IMService.access$400(IMService.java:66)
01-03 00:11:24.242 11157-11236/com.safarifone.waafi.debug W/System.err:     at com.safarifone.im.services.im.IMService$2.run(IMService.java:202)
01-03 00:11:24.242 11157-11236/com.safarifone.waafi.debug W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
01-03 00:11:24.243 11157-11236/com.safarifone.waafi.debug W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-03 00:11:24.243 11157-11236/com.safarifone.waafi.debug W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
01-03 00:11:24.243 11157-11236/com.safarifone.waafi.debug W/System.err:     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
```